# Split df columns by \n delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split my df every 3 rows OR by the \n delimiter. The df looks as follows:
[image]

I have attempted string replace but I would like to keep the index after the split occurs.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use str accessor as follows.

```
for i in range(3, df.columns, 3):
    df.drop(i, axis = 1, inplace = True) # remove column i
    df = pd.concat(df, df[i].str.split('\n', expand = True), axis = 1)
```